# I want to extract the string values that come first before a special character

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have column values in my data frame like `my_name_is_khan , hello|this|is|it` and so on . How do I use `str_extract` to do this? When I use `str_extract`, this is what I get. When i do not exactly know the character length before the first special char (- or |), what do I do ?

```
str_extract("my-name-is-khan", pattern = "[a-z]{1,6}")
[1] "my"
```

Comment: I want to string_split the col or extract the values ( before the special char) into a separate df

Comment: You can edit your question rather than tacking on clarifications in the comments.

Comment: Your question also not very clear, what I understood is that you want to get the first word before _ or | symbol. Try this: `str_extract(vect,"([a-zA-Z]+)(?=_|\\|)")` where `vect <- c("my_name_is_khan" , "hello|this|is|it")`

Comment: Another idea could be: `stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(vect, "[:alpha:]+")`

Comment: Thanks PKumar it works.

Comment: I've encountered another issue. When there is no _ or | in the string it throws "NA" . e.g., > str_extract("SHOLAY","([a-zA-Z]+)(?=_|\\|)")
[1] NA